# Premiere multicamera audio not working

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

I've got a project with two video tracks from two cameras, and an audio track from a separate recording (from neither camera). Everything is synced up, but when I convert this to multi-camera, Premiere will not play the audio. I see the audio track, but it has no wave form, and when I play the multi-camera track, I can edit and switch between the video feeds, but I still get no audio.

If relevant, the audio is mono, not stereo.

What am I doing wrong here?